# Restricting the order in which variables are allowed to enter in the LARS algorithm

Tags: regression, linear, lasso, lars

In the Least Angle Regression [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0406456.pdf), in section 3, the authors refer to how you can restrict the order in which variables are allowed to enter the LARS Algorithm. In particular, having obtained some prediction based on 4 of the 10 features, they recommend fitting the LARS algorithm again on the residual, with features given by what I am guessing are pointwise products of the two vectors (Hadamard product).

I struggle to intuit this step of the algorithm. Suppose that this process then tells you the interaction of feature X with Z is most correlated to the residual. How does this quantitatively imply that the order in which we introduce X or Z in LARS is important? I am further guessing that when they say it is straightforward to restrict the order of variable inclusion, you are overriding the naive LARS algorithm by excluding say some variables from the active set search.